# docker compose does not create containers, but I get no error messages

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container, docker-stack

I'm working through the official Docker CE (version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40) tutorial on Ubuntu 17.10, and I'm having problems running services as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3).  **The service won't start, but Docker won't tell me why.**

## Problem Description

When I start the service, this is what happens:

```
$ docker stack deploy -c ./docker-compose.yml compose-example 
Creating network compose-example_webnet
Creating service compose-example_web
$
```

No errors are returned, the exit status is 0, and nothing looks unusual.  However, when getting info about the stack...

```
$ docker stack ps compose-example 
ID                  NAME                        IMAGE                 NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE                 ERROR                              PORTS
cc01b85bh1si        compose-example_web.1       jessetg/example:2.1   jesse-ubuntu        Ready               Rejected 3 seconds ago        "container ingress-sbox is alr…"   
z0hleui2rnai         \_ compose-example_web.1   jessetg/example:2.1   jesse-ubuntu        Shutdown            Rejected 18 seconds ago       "container ingress-sbox is alr…"   
w47ajzunn7it         \_ compose-example_web.1   jessetg/example:2.1   jesse-ubuntu        Shutdown            Rejected 43 seconds ago       "container ingress-sbox is alr…"   
yca0lx87oasq         \_ compose-example_web.1   jessetg/example:2.1   jesse-ubuntu        Shutdown            Rejected 53 seconds ago       "container ingress-sbox is alr…"   
uvpvaperhcek         \_ compose-example_web.1   jessetg/example:2.1   jesse-ubuntu        Shutdown            Rejected about a minute ago   "container ingress-sbox is alr…"   
qgfvmdrysirb        compose-example_web.2       jessetg/example:2.1   jesse-ubuntu        Ready               Rejected 3 seconds ago        "container ingress-sbox is alr…"   
zgek1ga179a9         \_ compose-example_web.2   jessetg/example:2.1   jesse-ubuntu        Shutdown            Rejected 18 seconds ago       "container ingress-sbox is alr…"   
ybuzkik6rqqn         \_ compose-example_web.2   jessetg/example:2.1   jesse-ubuntu        Shutdown            Rejected 48 seconds ago       "container ingress-sbox is alr…"   
yx71seu5cxzx         \_ compose-example_web.2   jessetg/example:2.1   jesse-ubuntu        Shutdown            Rejected about a minute ago   "container ingress-sbox is alr…"   
yrdlrc5jwdyu         \_ compose-example_web.2   jessetg/example:2.1   jesse-ubuntu        Shutdown            Rejected about a minute ago   "container ingress-sbox is alr…"   
yuoegbfvo190        compose-example_web.3       jessetg/example:2.1   jesse-ubuntu        Ready               Rejected 3 seconds ago        "container ingress-sbox is alr…"   
zqft052r2len         \_ compose-example_web.3   jessetg/example:2.1   jesse-ubuntu        Shutdown            Rejected 28 seconds ago       "container ingress-sbox is alr…"   
zbpjg0yqrhon         \_ compose-example_web.3   jessetg/example:2.1   jesse-ubuntu        Shutdown            Rejected 53 seconds ago       "container ingress-sbox is alr…"   
y4cj9qlrlvkn         \_ compose-example_web.3   jessetg/example:2.1   jesse-ubuntu        Shutdown            Rejected 58 seconds ago       "container ingress-sbox is alr…"   
x3yljiu07mkq         \_ compose-example_web.3   jessetg/example:2.1   jesse-ubuntu        Shutdown            Rejected about a minute ago   "container ingress-sbox is alr…"   
nibomw8zsx6y        compose-example_web.4       jessetg/example:2.1   jesse-ubuntu        Ready               Rejected 3 seconds ago        "container ingress-sbox is alr…"   
we2uwo0gaka8         \_ compose-example_web.4   jessetg/example:2.1   jesse-ubuntu        Shutdown            Rejected 13 seconds ago       "container ingress-sbox is alr…"   
y5gs1uooes2b         \_ compose-example_web.4   jessetg/example:2.1   jesse-ubuntu        Shutdown            Rejected 38 seconds ago       "container ingress-sbox is alr…"   
w1dozapp04pv         \_ compose-example_web.4   jessetg/example:2.1   jesse-ubuntu        Shutdown            Rejected 48 seconds ago       "container ingress-sbox is alr…"   
wc9weak6gzfi         \_ compose-example_web.4   jessetg/example:2.1   jesse-ubuntu        Shutdown            Rejected about a minute ago   "container ingress-sbox is alr…"   
$
```

The `CURRENT STATE` column is filled entirely with rejections.  The truncated errors all say `"container ingress-sbox is already present in sandbox ingress_sbox"`.  Listing the individual containers looks like this:

```
$ docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND             CREATED              STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
3c42933ddabe        jessetg/example:2.1   "python3 app.py"    About a minute ago   Created                                 compose-example_web.4.b6r18eot53o23afx2csl0dnqi
59f6073c3ebd        jessetg/example:2.1   "python3 app.py"    12 minutes ago       Created                                 compose-example_web.2.hi2m5am7dsf6rumecr69kxv3t
$
```

However, running the container alone (i.e. not in a swarm or a stack) works exactly as expected.

## Relevant Files

### `Dockerfile`

```docker
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.6-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 80

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME World

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python3", "app.py"]
```

### `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: jessetg/example:2.1
    deploy:
      replicas: 4
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 64M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "80:4001"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

### `app.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from flask import Flask
from redis import Redis, RedisError
import os
import socket

# Connect to Redis
redis = Redis(host="redis", db=0, socket_connect_timeout=2, socket_timeout=2)

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    try:
        visits = redis.incr("counter")
    except RedisError:
        visits = "<i>cannot connect to Redis, counter disabled</i>"

    html = "<h3>Hello {name}!</h3>" \
           "<b>Hostname:</b> {hostname}<br/>" \
           "<b>Visits:</b> {visits}"
    return html.format(name=os.getenv("NAME", "world"), hostname=socket.gethostname(), visits=visits)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

Comment: From your docker-compose config - there are 4 replicas all attempting to listen on the same port? Try stopping all containers, changing replicas to 1, and then deploying stack again. That'll tell you if there are port conflicts.

Comment: @Timir Nope, no change in outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get an error about creating a network like the one you're experiencing, "container ingress-sbox is already present in sandbox ingress_sbox", it's worth checking your Linux kernel.

Things to look out for on the kernel side include:

- Mismatch between installed modules package and the running kernel (if the running kernel can't load a required module, then you'll get stuck).
- The running kernel has certain required features disabled.

In the case of a mismatch, a reboot will usually get you running your newly installed kernel package, which means you'll actually be able to load the necessary modules.

In the case that the kernel you are running simply has the feature disabled entirely, you may need to switch to a different kernel altogether.

Answer (score -2):

There is no way in docker to catch exceptions, but to log exceptions in a file and then you navigate inside container to check , till its alive .You can use

> docker exec -it container id bash

to go inside it or use

> docker diff container id

to check for added files or modified file which will be your log files, as every time logs will be appended to your log file.This is the way , we track our exceptions or if you come across , any better way please share .

Comment: Thank you for letting me know.  When I get home I will give this a try and report back.